# How to select rows with x but not y or z using HAVING in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query and not sure if I'm using HAVING correctly.
Basically, I have users with certain products. I want to find users that have 'X' product and not ('Y' and/or 'Z'). It's ok for them to have 'X' and/or 'A' and/or 'B', etc. just not 'X' and ('Y' and/or 'Z').

What I have do far but is not removing the users with my criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM users_product_version upv
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT upv.user_id
                  FROM users_product_version upv
                  JOIN product_version pv ON upv.product_id = pv.id
                  JOIN product p ON pv.priority_product_id = p.id
                  WHERE p.id = '89'
                  GROUP BY upv.user_id)
GROUP BY upv.product_id
HAVING upv.product_id NOT IN ('9562','9563','9564');
```

Select these users:

```
1: X, A, B, F

2: X

3: X, G
```

**Don't** select these users:

```
1: X, Y, A

2: Y

3: BLANK

4: X, Y, Z
```

My `users_product_version` table holds the `product_id`'s.
I've also tried `GROUP BY user_id, product_id`. I'm almost certain I'm making this too complicated than it is. Does anyone have any tips? Thank you.

Comment: `not 'Y' and/or 'Z'.` should be `(not 'Y' and not  'Z')` isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Maybe. They should not have any combination of (X and/or Y) products. BAD=(X,Y,X) (X,Y) (X,Z) GOOD= (X) (X,A) etc.

Comment: @ChadH Should they always have an `'X'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the query this way:

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users_product_version AS u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_product_version AS u2
  ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.product_id IN ('Y', 'Z')
WHERE u1.product_id = 'X'
  AND u2.user_id IS NULL;
```

By the WHERE clause, the user must have 'X'.

In the LEFT OUTER JOIN, we *try* to find another row where that user has either 'Y' or 'Z'. We want there to be no match for such a row, so we have a condition that some column from that table (user_id) must be NULL. This will happen by virtue of the outer join when there is no match.

I think you misunderstand what HAVING is for. HAVING is for applying a condition to a *group* after you have done GROUP BY.

Writing a condition in the HAVING clause that compares a column to a single scalar value makes no sense. There might be multiple rows in the group, with different values for product_id.

You could use an aggregate function like GROUP_CONCAT() to the group of rows, and then compare that in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_product_version
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('X', GROUP_CONCAT(product_id))
  AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('Y', GROUP_CONCAT(product_id)) 
  AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('Z', GROUP_CONCAT(product_id));
```

But this is probably going to be inefficient.

---

Re your comments, to look up names of the product_id attributes.

You can use parentheses with joins, just like you would with arithmetic, to control the order of evaluation.

Joining:

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN (B INNER JOIN C)
```

Joins B to C to produce a set of rows. Then that becomes the operand of the outer join.

It's important to use parentheses in this example, because

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN B INNER JOIN C
```

would produce a much different result. Supposing the join to C references columns from B, it would require that the columns from B are non-NULL. This would implicitly turn the OUTER JOIN B into an INNER JOIN B, because it wouldn't allow cases where there was no B matching A.

Here's how to apply it to your query:

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users_product_version AS u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  users_product_version AS u2 INNER JOIN products AS p 
  ON u2.product_id = p.product_id AND u2.product_id IN ('book', 'food')
) ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id 
WHERE u1.product_id = 'X'
  AND u2.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey Bill. I really appreciate the reply. I believe this is working best and I actually understand your solution. I used your first block of code without `having` keyword. I have an additional question if i can... So say I expand the first block of code to include another joined table for the `AND u2.product_id IN ('Y', 'Z')` to join a related table for the `IN ('Y', 'Z') ` bit. So say I have another table with the actual name instead of `product_id`.

Comment: So say Y = book, Z = food how can I `left join users_product_version on u1.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.product_id IN ('book', 'food')`. Would that just be  a normal join under `users_product_version` and switch `u2.product_id` with, say, `p.productNames = ('book', 'food)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want users with `'X'` but do not have `'Y'` or `'Z'`:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM users_product_version
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN product_id IN ('Y', 'Z') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```